# Modal that displays conditionally with async pipe wont display twice

Tags: angular, error-handling, rxjs

Hey I have a modal I am using which is basically listening to an subject observable and the global http interceptor is pushing an error onto it

so this works great for the first error:

```
<modal
  modalwidth="50"
  open="true"
  label="Oh no!"
  *ngIf="errorMessage$ | async as errorMessage"
>
```

if on the same page though you cause another error this modal does not appear again, so you get the first error - modal appears, you close it - cause another error and the modal never appears.

http interceptor calls handleError->

```
private errorMessageSubject = new Subject<CustomError>();
  public errorMessage$ = this.errorMessageSubject.asObservable();

  handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse): void {
    this.errorMessageSubject.next({
```

then on the root of the Angular app in the app.component.ts

```
 this.errorMessage$ = this.errorService.errorMessage$;
```

I believe what I need to reset the observable somehow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After closing modal emit `void`:

```
this.errorMessageSubject.next(void 0);
```